# Angular automatically select the Mat-Select when there is only one option

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, select, angular6

I need to set default value if there is one one option in the mat-select. otherwise leave black to select by user.
This is my code in HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select (selectionChange)="CompartSelected($event, element, cmpart)" disableRipple [value]="element.Compart.Id" name="cmpart" >
  <mat-option *ngIf="getAvailableCompartList(element.Compart.CompartType.Id).length > 1" value="">-- Please Select an Option --</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let cmpart of getAvailableCompartList(element.Compart.CompartType.Id)" title="{{Translate(cmpart.CompartNote)}}" 
      [value]="cmpart.Id">{{cmpart.CompartTitle}}
  </mat-option>
```

according to the @Sean solution I have update the code. But it doesn't set the value to the mat-select.
I have attached some pic of those mat-select.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry - misunderstood.  You want the value selected when there is only one option (default behavior), otherwise leave blank when 2+ options are available.  Add an additional mat-option outside of your ngFor only when the ngFor expression returns more than 1 item.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="CompartSelected($event, element, cmpart)" disableRipple [value]="element.Compart.Id" name="cmpart" >
      <mat-option *ngIf="getAvailableCompartList(element.Compart.CompartType.Id).length > 1" value="">-- Please Select an Option --</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let cmpart of getAvailableCompartList(element.Compart.CompartType.Id)" title="{{Translate(cmpart.CompartNote)}}" 
          [value]="cmpart.Id">{{cmpart.CompartTitle}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can clean this up a little by placing the function call to `getAvailableCompartList` inside your component so you're not eval'ing the function twice as the template is rendered.

Comment: I have used this solution. But it doesnt set the value to the mat-select.

Comment: Thank you @sean, I have solved that one. But it doesn't trigger my (selectionChange) event in mat-select

Comment: @hash, you said you have solved this one. Would you please post your solution and accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still looking for a hint.
Normally when your select vary the size, means it is coming from an observable.
So you could do this:

Typescript code:

```
//HERE IS THE FUNCTION THAT LOADS YOUR OPTIONS. IN THIS CASE 'val' IS MY API RETURN.
//IN CASE SIZE IS 1, PASS THE FIRST VALUE TO YOUR VARIABLE MODEL.

        loadParameter(){
                this.service.getParameters().subscribe((val: any) => {             
                  this.parameters = val; 
                  if (val.length == 1) {
                    this.selectedParameter = val[0].ParameterId;
                  }
                });
    }

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here the front code:
     
            <mat-label>Example</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedParameter">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let parameter of parameters" [value]="parameter.ParameterId">{{parameter.ParameterValue}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```